# error al crear un Repository en Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente error al querer iniciar mi aplicación de ejemplo:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
> [2m2020-11-19 17:09:22.045[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m12880[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoriasRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class model.Categoria

mi clase principal

```
package dbc.tienda;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import dbc.tienda.repository.categoriasRepository;
import model.Categoria;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TiendaDemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private categoriasRepository repo;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TiendaDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        guardar();
    }
    private void guardar(){
        Categoria cat =new Categoria();
        cat.setTipo("mueble");
        repo.save(cat);
        System.out.println(cat);
    }

}
```

mi clase Modelo

```
package model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="categorias")
public class Categoria {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String tipo;
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }
    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Categoria [id=" + id + ", tipo=" + tipo + "]";
    }   
}
```

Mi Interfaz repositorio de mi clase modelo

```
package dbc.tienda.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import model.Categoria;

public interface categoriasRepository extends CrudRepository<Categoria, Integer> {

}
```

No entiendo el error. E seguido al pie de la letra el tutorial y no me falta nada.

Comment: Agrega el anotation @Repository y me cuentas

Comment: en donde la agrego?

Comment: En la línea anterior a public interface categoriasRepository. Ahí agrega el anotation.

Comment: muchas gracias era eso, pero por que en su ejemplo no daba ese error y veo que el no tiene la anotación @Repository, es por la versión, la mía es la 2.4 y la del ejemplo es la 2.3? hay muchas diferencias entre versiones?

Comment: No debe ser por eso. Yo estoy usando versión 2.1 y es obligatorio

Comment: Si te sirvió mí respuesta marcala por favor como respuesta positiva así cierras la pregunta. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que spring reconozca que se trata de un repositorio y pueda ser definido como @Autowired, se debe indicar la anotación @Repository en la interface de repositorio. De esta manera spring sabe que es un repositorio y puede definirlo automáticamente.